# Breaking out of a 'for' loop

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, break

I'm supposed to use this code

```
for (i=1; i<4; i++)
{
    for (j=1; j, 4; j++)
    {
        printf("Running i=%d j=%d\n", i, j);
    }
}
```

... with this code to break it out of its loop

```
if (i==2 && j ==1) {
    printf("Break inner loop when i=%d and j=%d\n", i, j);
    break;
}
```

My textbook said to insert this `break` statement at the very beginning of the inner loop block. I don't know where that is! I've tried a lot of places already and still can't figure it out.

Here my whole program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j;

    for (i=1; i<4; i++)
    {
        for (j=1; j,4; j++)
            if (i==2 && j ==1) {
                printf("Break inner loop when i=%d and j=%d\n", i, j);
                break;
            }
            printf("Running i=%d j=%d\n", i, j);

        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

I figured it out: it had a typo

Comment: just before your `printf` statement and after the `{` You also have 2 `{` and 3 `}`...these have to match.

Comment: @paddy you just fixed one of the errors with formatting (unmatching braces) :)

Comment: You sure about C# in the title, bud? printf and %d don't look C# to my eyes.

Comment: Haha @Bill - I may have inadvertently done that.  The original question was so cluttered and nasty, I may have just assumed that the code was correct.  But yeah I vaguely recall seeing 3 closing braces.

Comment: Do note that you have `j,4` as the condition in your inner `for` loop (line 3), where you probably intended to have `j<4`.

Answer (score 2):

The beginning of the inner-loop block is just after the `{` on the second `for`:

```
for(i=1;i<4;i++)
{
    for(j=1;j,4;j++)
    {
        // <<<--- They mean here.
        printf("Running i=%d j=%d\n", i, j);
    }
}
```

Note that the `break` will only break out of the inner loop.  The outer loop will go around again.  If you need to break out of *both* loops you will need to add a flag of some sort.

Just noticed that you have a typo in your inner loop that is actually valid C (the comma operator).  It should have been `<`:

```
   for(j=1;j<4;j++)
```

Comment: There is another way to break out of both and that is to use an anonymous method. Put the loops in the anonymous method and return instead of breaking. It will return to the current method and continue. If this was c#... And apparently it was retagged

Comment: That's assuming this is actually C#.  But to me, it looks like C.  And no, I'm not going to recommend `goto`.

Comment: DO NOT USE GOTO (all caps to emphasis my statement) :)

Comment: Not sure if j,4 is a valid condition, yes the comma introduces a sequence point but I wonder how the compiler treats j,4 at all...on ipad, can't check

Comment: @0A0D yes, it is valid, but it's pointless and incorrect (`j,4` evaluates to `4`, which is always true).

Comment: @Bill: `goto` is the best option for breaking out of nested loops and handling errors in C. Sure, don’t use it when there are better options, but a wholesale ban is just silly.

Comment: @JonPurdy I said "do not" not "never". I agree with you, and +1 for `"a wholesale ban is just silly"` :)

Comment: @Bill: Okay, just making sure. :)

Comment: +1 for the selective and careful use of `goto`.  There really aren't too many places where you need it these days, but it's silly to abandon it when it really is the right tool.

Answer (score 1):

It would be in your second for block, so above or below the print statement. It's the only place it can go given the scope of the variables.

Comment: yeah i tried that it just kept looping

Comment: It keeps looping because your inner loop condition only checks that `j` is non-zero.  I'd better fix that for you.

Comment: @user2359407: did you read the text in the printf statement? It is only going to break the inner loop

Answer (score 0):

The break in the inner loop will bring you out of the inner for loop when i == 2 and j == 1, thus it won't run the function `printf("Running i=%d j=%d\n", i, j);`

It is continuing looping, because the code still needs to run the loops until both i and j are less than 4.